# Array to string conversion object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array, woocommerce

In woocommerce, I am trying to get the data from a multidimensional array from an Advanced custom field (ACF) to populate `woocommerce_form_field()` select field options.

If I `print_r` the data from:

```
$pickup = get_field_object('pick_up', 'pick_up_list')['value'];
```

I have this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Hotel Cla
            [price] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ritz Carlon
            [price] => 7
        )

)
```

Then I'm getting the error `Array to string conversion in` when using this array in:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'pick_up_list', array(
     'type'          => 'select',
     'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
     'label'         => __('Pick Up'),
     'options'       => $pickup
 ));
```

What I want is to be able to add the `$pickup` array as select field. Any help?

Comment: I'm not a Wordpress user/developer, but you can use `get_field()` which returns `array` instead of `get_field_object()` and retyping that. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/. Is it what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can be also done in a simple `FOR` loop, keeping both `'name'` and `'price'` values as `<option>` submitted value:

```
$pickup = get_field_object('pick_up', 'pick_up_list')['value'];

$options = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < count($pickup); $i++ ){
    $options[$pickup[$i]['name'].'_'.$pickup[$i]['price']] = $pickup[$i]['name'];
}

woocommerce_form_field( 'pick_up_list', array(
     'type'          => 'select',
     'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
     'label'         => __('Pick Up'),
     'options'       => $options
));
```

Then once the data  will be submitted, you will get it both `'name'` and `'price'` this way:

```
if( isset($_POST['pick_up_list']) ){
    $pick_up_list = sanitize_text_field($_POST['pick_up_list']);
    $pick_up_list = explode('_', $pick_up_list); // Separate the merged data

    $name  = $pick_up_list[0]; // The hotel name
    $price = $pick_up_list[1]; // The hotel price
}
```

Comment: How to add in `$cart_item['pick_up_list'] = explode('_', $pick_up_list[0]);`.. show error array.

Answer (score 1):

**options** should be an associative array key => value, try this:

```
$options = array();
foreach($pickup as $index => $values) {
    $options[$index] = $values['name'];
}
```

Then, call the function:

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'pick_up_list', array(
   'type'          => 'select',
   'class'         => array('form-row-wide'),
   'label'         => __('Pick Up'),
   'options'       => $options
));
```

Comment: but no take [price] in options :/